# Using unordered_map allocator's not default constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unordered-map, tr1

I would like to use a different `allocator` than the default one in `unordered_map`.
For my specific `allocator`, I want to call another constructor than the default one (I want to pass an `int` to the constructor).
I think the problem is that `unordered_map` calls the `default constructor` of my `allocator`.

So, Eventually I want to do something like that:

Instead of calling this `unordered_map` constructor:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int, std::tr1::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, MyAllocatorNs::MyAllocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > unorderedMap;
```

I want to do something like that:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int, std::tr1::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, MyAllocatorNs::MyAllocator<std::pair<const int, int> >(3) > unorderedMap;
```

Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: [Will passing the allocator instance in the map constructor work for you?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unordered_map` allows you to pass in an instance of the allocator as an argument rather than defaulting to the zero-argument constructor.

```
typedef MyAllocatorNs::MyAllocator<std::pair<const int, int> > AllocatorType;
unordered_map<int, int, hash<int>, equal_to<int>, AllocatorType > unorderedMap (AllocatorType(3));
```